# Confused about rectangles in ruby

Tags: ruby, rectangles

This code takes the coordinates of two rectangles and finds their intersection.

```
def rec_intersection(rect1, rect2)
  x_min = [rect1[0][0], rect2[0][1]].max
  x_max = [rect1[1][0], rect2[1][1]].min
  y_min = [rect1[0][0], rect2[0][1]].max
  y_max = [rect1[1][0], rect2[1][1]].min
  return nil if ((x_max < x_min) || (y_max < y_min))
  return [[x_min, y_min], [x_max, y_max]]
end

rec_intersection([[1, 1], [2, 2]],[[0, 0], [5, 5]])
```

I don't really understand it. Specifically I would like to know more about exactly what the coordinates mean (I know they are coordinates for the left-bottom and right-top) but can anybody elaborate more? What are they relative to? The size of the rectangle? Or it's placement? How does a rectangle with a bottom-left coordinate of [1,1] differ from one with a bottom-left of [0,0]?

Also I would like to know why in order to find the x_min, the max method is being used (and vice-versa). Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: Your worship, rectangles are commonly specified by giving the coordinates for two opposite corners.  In your example, `rect1 = [[1,1],[2,2]]`, so `[1,1]` would be the coordinate for the top-left corner and `[2,2]` would be the coordinate in the bottom-right corner.  The other two corners therefore would be at `[1,2]` (top-right) and `[2,1]` (bottom-left).

Comment: so in the second rectangle the top-left coordinates are [0,0] compared to the first rectangle's top-left of [1,1] ...so what does that tell me about the rectangles? that they are different in size, or location?... since they are both top-lefts

Comment: @HolyMoly both. It sounds like maybe you should spend some time catching up with Pythagoras or Descartes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a comment, which I will delete after the OP has seen it. Here's a graph of the two rectangles, where `rect1` is contained within `rect2`.

[image]

Earlier, where I referred to `[1,1]` and `[2,2]` as the "top-left" and "bottom-right" corners, respectively, of `rect1`, that should have been the "bottom-left" and "top-right" corners.