# Rectangle intersection in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, intersection, intersect

I'm trying to understand this program, but I'm having some difficulty. I don't understand the part with `x_min`, `y_min`, `x_max`, `y_max`.

I understand the program passes through two rectangles with the bottom-left and top-right coordinate points, but where do the array indices `[0][0]`,`[1][1]`, etc. come from?

I'm confused about what's happening, so an explanation would help.

```
# Write a function, `rec_intersection(rect1, rect2)` and returns the
# intersection of the two.
#
# Rectangles are represented as a pair of coordinate-pairs: the
# bottom-left and top-right coordinates (given in `[x, y]` notation).
#
# Hint: You can calculate the left-most x coordinate of the
# intersection by taking the maximum of the left-most x coordinate of
# each rectangle. Likewise, you can calculate the top-most y
# coordinate of the intersection by taking the minimum of the top most
# y coordinate of each rectangle.
#
# Difficulty: 4/5
def rec_intersection(rect1, rect2)

x_min = [rect1[0][0], rect2[0][0]].max
x_max = [rect1[1][0], rect2[1][0]].min

y_min = [rect1[0][1], rect2[0][1]].max
y_max = [rect1[1][1], rect2[1][1]].min

return nil if ((x_max < x_min) || (y_max < y_min))
return [[x_min, y_min], [x_max, y_max]]
end

puts rec_intersection(
      [[0, 0], [2, 1]],
      [[1, 0], [3, 1]]
    ) == [[1, 0], [2, 1]]

puts rec_intersection(
      [[1, 1], [2, 2]],
      [[0, 0], [5, 5]]
    ) == [[1, 1], [2, 2]]


puts rec_intersection(
      [[1, 1], [2, 2]],
      [[4, 4], [5, 5]]
    ) == nil

puts rec_intersection(
      [[1, 1], [5, 4]],
      [[2, 2], [3, 5]]
    ) == [[2, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: The answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29157419/confused-about-rectangles-in-ruby) may be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I don't get in particular is the part with x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max. I get the the program passes through 2 rectangles with the bottom left and top right coordinate points. But where do the array indices come from? [0][0] , [1][1], etc?

This section of the comments above that code is important to understand this:

```
# Rectangles are represented as a pair of coordinate-pairs: the
# bottom-left and top-right coordinates (given in `[x, y]` notation).
```

So, if `rect` is a rectangle, then `rect[0]` represents the bottom-left corner, and `rect[1]` represents the top-right corner. Further, `rect[0][0]` represents the x-coordinate of the bottom-left corner, `rect[0][1]` is the y-coordinate of that corner, and so on.

This section of the comments is also important:

```
# Hint: You can calculate the left-most x coordinate of the
# intersection by taking the maximum of the left-most x coordinate of
# each rectangle. [...]
```

If `rect` is a rectangle, the left-most x-coordinate of that rectangle is the x-coordinate of the bottom-left corner. As I explained above, `rect[0][0]` represents the x-coordinate of the bottom-left corner. So, in this line:

```
x_min = [rect1[0][0], rect2[0][0]].max
```

`rect1[0][0]` and `rect2[0][0]` are the two leftmost x-coordinates of the rectangles, and this line of code is saying that the x-coordinate of the leftmost side of the intersection of the two rectangles is equal to whichever one of these is bigger.

Comment: Thanks so much! I started to sort of work it out but this provides lots of clarity for me

Answer (score 8):

The variables `x_min`, `x_max`, `y_min`, `y_max` are used to store the coordinates of the intersecting region. They are obtained using `max` and `min` on a two-value array using the passed-in rectangles. Calling `[1 ,2].max` will return `2`, and calling `[1,2].min` will return `1` for example.

The reason why these variables represent the intersecting rectangle is probably easier to understand through an image (extremely detailed and professional diagram incoming):
[image: rectangle intersect for dummies]

As you can see, the minimum value of the yellow (intersecting) rectangle can be no less than the minimum value of the red rectangle. The max value can be no less than the blue rectangle's max value.

Comment: It was just a little joke

Comment: Very nice, thanks, seriously went above and beyond here.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when it's looking for the maximum of the `x_min` or the min of the `x_max`, it's asking firstly "which array of x values" then it's asking "which value".

The code 
`x_min = [rect1[0][0], rect2[0][0]].max`

is specifically looking for [rect1 [the first array (0)] [the first value (0)]